# How to plot a function over a very wide range?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot some one-variable functions over a very large range, say for example:

```
Plot[3 t, {t, 0, 10^800}]
```

However I get an error saying:

```
Plot::plln: Limiting value 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000<<581>>00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in {<<1>>} is not a machine-sized real number.
```

So, how can I get around this and obtain a proper plot while keeping the wide range?

Comment: Rescaling. The plot routines work internaly with machine precision. The largest number representable in machine precision is `$MaxMachineNumber` (about $10^{308}$). So you have to rescale.

Comment: Use `LogPlot` or `LogLogPlot`.

Answer (score 3):

```
LogLogPlot[3 t, {t, 0, 10^800}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}`:

```
Plot[3 t, {t, 0, 10^800}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]